# Type Mismatched in VBA

Tags: excel, type-mismatch, vba

I am trying to run this code:

```
Function Main()
 Dim arr() As Variant
 arrValues = Range("D2:D106")
 arr = arrValues

End Function
```

---

```
Function stAvg()
Dim CustList() As Variant

Dim forecast() As Double

CustList = Main()

'loop through array to find average
For X = 1 To 52
        forecastNumber = WorksheetFunction.Average(CustList(X, 1), CustList(X + 1, 1), CustList(X + 2, 1), CustList(X + 3, 1))
        forecast(X) = forecastNumber
    Next X

    For X = 1 To 3
        MsgBox forecast(X, 1)
    Next X


End Function
```

After I use the debugger I get an error message that tells me I have a type mismatch at the end of the Main function. However the error message is sort of vague, and I cannot tell what the problem is. Help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `Main` to be a `Function`, at least as you're showing it here, since it doesn't return anything. So I made it a `Sub`.

For your actual quesiton, just set `arr` equal to the `Range`. As I noted in an comment to an answer to another question of yours, use `arr`, not `arr()`.

```
Sub Main()
Dim arr As Variant

arr = Range("D2:D106")
End Sub
```

EDIT: To use it as a function:

```
Function Main() as Variant
Dim arr As Variant

arr = Range("D2:D106")
Main = arr
End Function
```

Call it like:

```
Dim CustList As Variant
...
CustList = Main()
```

Just as a stylistic note `Main` generally designates the main subroutine in a program, so I'd call the function seomething like `GetRangeValues`.

Comment: Hey,  I do want to return the array, arr so the the other function can use those values. Any suggestions?

Comment: you're not setting `Main` to anything so `CustList` will always be empty

Comment: @Brad, arrgh, first I forgot, then I stuck it in the original version. Now I think I've got it right. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you never return anything from the function. You assign some local variables, which does not make sense. You have to actually return a value, which in VB6(A) you do by assigning a value to the function name:

```
Function Main()
  Main = Range("D2:D106").Value
End Function
```

Then you can use it:

```
Dim CustList() As Variant

CustList = Main()
```

Comment: Why do you declare CustList as an array of `Variants`? Also, I would (and did for that matter) explicitly declare Main as a `Variant`.

Comment: @DougGlancy I tried to do as few changes to the OP's code as possible to put the emphasis on the main point. Yes you can make that better. Declaring `Variant` vs `Variant()` is an open question because `Value` returns `Variant -> Variant()`, and VBA will automatically pick up either part of it depending on the type of the receiving variable.

Answer (score 0):

To use Worksheet function you shoukld use a RAnge Object and not an Array.
For that, changed main to return your range

```
Function Main()
    Set Main = Range("D2:D106")
End Function
```

Changed the Average to reference the Cells position from the range

```
Function stAvg()
    Dim CustList
    Dim forecast(52)

    Set CustList = Main()

    'loop through array to find average
    For X = 1 To 52
        forecastNumber = WorksheetFunction.Average(CustList.Cells(X, 1), CustList.Cells(X + 1, 1),         CustList.Cells(X + 2, 1), CustList.Cells(X + 3, 1))
    forecast(X) = forecastNumber
    Next X

    For X = 1 To 3
        MsgBox forecast(X, 1)
    Next X
End Function
```

Comment: Try NetWorkDays passing array of dates in the holidays

Comment: Even though `NetWorkDays` is a part of the analysis toolpack, an external addin, and not an intrinsic Excel function found under `Application.WorksheetFunction`, it still supports arrays: `? networkdays(now, now + 10, array(now + 5, now + 7, now + 9))` yields `6` (currently).